# Which Exception class to use?

Tags: java, exception

I have written a music player in Java, but I have a problem with finding an exception to throw. Basically, what I want the exception handler to throw is if a filename of a song stored in the playlist is altered or if the file is deleted, as naturally, in that case it won't play. I first thought it was an IOException I would need, but it gave me the error saying

> exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Now, I understand that that means that I'm working with the wrong Exception class, and so I tried to write my own that extends Exception, but it gives me the same error when I try to compile. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

This is the method as it is right now:

```
public void play() throws NoMatchException
    {
        if(player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }      

        try{
            int fileToPlay = tracklist.getSelectedIndex();
            String filename = organizer.getFile(fileToPlay);
            Media song = new Media(filename);
            player = new MediaPlayer(song);
            setVolume(currentVolume);
            player.play();

            player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() { next(); }
            });   
        }
        catch (NoMatchException e){
            //Some exception
        }              
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are not sure what exception you need to catch, go to the documentation of the corresponding method. It turns out that the [constructor of `Media`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29) would throw [`MediaException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaException.html) - this is the exception that you need to catch. Scroll down to the "throws" section, and look for the exceptions that do *not* extend `RuntimeException` (runtime exceptions usually indicate programming errors; the need to catch this is rare).

When you are deciding to catch an exception at a particular level of your program, see if your code can do something meaningful about it. You shouldn't be catching exceptions unless you know what to do when to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

This code makes no sense.

Your `catch` block is empty and does *nothing*.  Your method says it throws a `NoMatchException`.  Why don't you eliminate the try/catch and let it do so?

You catch exceptions when you have a viable strategy for recovering.  Doing nothing is not a strategy.  Just let it bubble up and let the caller deal with it.

If you do have a viable recovery strategy, implement it in the catch block and remove the throws clause from the method signature.  Either one or the other, but not both.

Comment: It's empty cause I didn't bother to write it until I knew how to make it work. Basically, I just want to print a notification to the user that there is a problem with the file she is trying to play.